# Typescript why can't return header in function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, header, frontend

I am new to typescript. I have a value for headers that I was uses that worked fine. I tried separating it into another function that would be called, but then it doesn't work.

Here is the code without being called

```
var headers: any = "";
try {
    const token = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token
    };
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
axios
    .get("https://localhost:", { getHeader })
```

This worked file when doing a .get with headers as a parameter. But when I try to turn it into a function.

```
export function getHeader () {
                  let headers: Record<string, string | null> = {}; // this line

                  const token = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

                  headers = {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token
                  };



                  return headers
}
```

It throws an error.

```
Type 'Record<string, string | null>' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
```

'string' index signatures are incompatible.
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.

How can I just make it work as a function?

Edit: The try catch block was incorrect. Fixed it.

Edit: Added the updated code from comments with the error message.

Comment: The second code snippet is full of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass the entire function to the axios config, instead of using the result of that function.

Try this instead:

```
axios.get("https://localhost:", { headers: getHeader() })
```

On a different note, you have small problems in your `getHeader` function -

- You can use `Record` instead of `any`
- You shouldn't initialize the variable as a different type than what you expect - why an empty `string`? Use an empty object instead
- It's preferable to use `const` or `let` instead of `var`

```
export function getHeader () {
                  let headers: Record<string, string> = {}; // this line

                  const token = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
                  headers = {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token
                  };
                  } catch (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                  }

                  return headers
}
```

Comment: There is no real reason to have `headers` initialised to something temporarily anyway. Just directly assign the object. Then it can be `const`. And use the implicit typing, instead of `Record`, since it would be less error-prone.

Comment: I agree - I was trying to fix the problems without modifying the code too heavily, and leaving OP even more confused. One step at a time :)

Comment: This fixed the problem but it is saying "Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'." for the token part of the header value. Am I using that wrong in the function as opposed to when it was outside the function?

Comment: `getCookie` seems to either return a `string` or `null`, you can change to `Record<string, string | null>`

Comment: If it is saying Record<string, string | null> is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders', do I need to export it as a type AxiosRequestHeaders?